# Comparison of PostgreSQL text types

Tags: postgresql

I'm migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL because Oracle. There is a great [MySQL text type reference](http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php), here is the relevant information for MySQL...

> CHAR( )       A fixed section from 0 to 255 characters long.
>
> VARCHAR( )    A variable section from 0 to 255 characters long.
>
> TINYTEXT  A string with a maximum length of 255 characters.
>
> TEXT      A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.
>
> BLOB      A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.
>
> MEDIUMTEXT    A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.
>
> MEDIUMBLOB    A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.
>
> LONGTEXT  A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.
>
> LONGBLOB  A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.

PostgreSQL seems a bit different, there is a `text` type looking through phppgAdmin, not sure what else there is and I'm not finding any good comparison tables.

What are all the available text types in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Want a good advice? Use pgAdminIII instead of phpPgAdmin. It is **much** better. Also, [dba.se] and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html - or rather the [whole chapter about data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype.html).

Comment: @ThiefMaster I've got both though pgAdmin III does seem to have a create table option. Also are tables *supposed* to be a child of schemas or is that some default oddity?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: Everything is inside a schema. Usually the *public* schema is fine. A nice usecase for schemas is in huge databases where you want to group your tables a big.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm actually building a reference table for quick cross-referencing between MySQL and PostgreSQL. I've got three tabs open with the documentation fyi.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are asking. All character data types are documented in the manual (including the performance difference and the differences in behaviour)

Comment: @John Just use `text` for any type of text you want to store. If you really need a size constraint - just create a `CONSTRAINT` on that table. There is almost no reason to use anything other than `text`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PostgreSQL has more advanced types but doesn't need the distinction between text sizes.

There are 3 string types in PostgreSQL and a binary type:

**text**

Just a text object with a non-specified size. You can put anything in here and it will be stored. Size doesn't matter.

**varchar(n)** / **character varying(n)**

Basically a text which has a size check, there is virtually no (except for checking the size while inserting) performance difference here.

**char(n)** / **character(n)**

Just a text where all the extra characters will be padded with space characters so you always get `n` characters back.

**bytea**

The blob type you've mentioned is a totally different type alltogether. You could replace it with the `bytea` type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-binary.html

---

Source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html